# Point domain to node express server on Azure

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, express

This must be an extremely common problem. I've seen various answers for this but none seem to work for me.

I have node installed on an apache server on Windows Azure. My app is built and ready to go (snippet below):

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

//example api call
app.get("/api/example", function(req, res){

  //do some process
  res.send(data);

});

app.listen(8080);
console.log("App listening on port 8080");
```

Now, when testing on my own computer, I could then go to `localhost:8080`, which works great. But now I've put it on the azure server I can't get an external domain to point to it properly. So for example, I have the domain:

```
framework.example.com
```

I've added this to my hosts file in Azure:

```
XXX.0.0.01 framework.example.com
```

Initially I tried also editing the `http-vhosts.conf` to point the domain to the correct directory. This worked for loading the frontend, but the app couldn't talk to the backend. API calls returned 400 not found errors.

I've also tried an Express vhost method but think I'm doing it wrong and don't fully understand it. What is the correct method?!

My app structure is like this:

```
- package.json
- server.js
- server
  - files used by server.js
- public
  - all frontend files
```

So to boot the server I run `server.js` which runs the code at the top. The server.js uses the below Express config to point to the public folder.

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding it to the hosts file in Azure won't help. You'll need to configure your domain's DNS to point to Azure. I'd recommend using the DNS Name of your Cloud Service instance. Your underlying VM IP address could change if you need to stop it for some reason, but your Cloud Service DNS name is configured to always route to your underlying VMs. That means you'll need to setup a CNAME with your DNS.

Read more about that here: [Cloud Services Custom Domain Name](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-custom-domain-name/)

Next, you'll either need to host the node app on port 80, or put a proxy in front of it to handle that for you. Otherwise you'll be stuck typing `framework.example.com:8080` which is not ideal. On linux, you'll likely need to be a privileged user to host on port 80, but you never want your node app to have root privileges. You can use [authbind](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/authbind.1.html) to work around this problem.

See an example of how to use it with node here: [Using authbind with Node.js](https://thomashunter.name/blog/using-authbind-with-node-js/)

All that being said, it seems like you're somewhat new with linux server management. If that's the case, I'd strongly recommend trying to use something like [Azure Websites](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-nodejs-develop-deploy-mac/) instead of a VM. You no longer have to manage the virtual machine OS. You simply tell it to host your application and it takes care of the rest. If you're using github, this is incredibly easy to test and iterate with. It does host on Windows under the hood, and that might problems for some applications, but I host all my node sites there (developed on Mac) without any issues.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've already configured the DNS for the domain. Like I said in my question, I could get the frontend to load, but I wasn't doing the routing correctly so the backend API would work. Yes I'm fairly new to using Azure but I have to use the VM for various other reasons. I'll look at the links you posted.

Comment: I didn't see anything about DNS in your question. The hosts file will only update how your server handles requests. If your API requests are running from the browser, it won't help. Can you provide more details about what you're trying to do, and what isn't working? What is the backend? How is it being called? Where do you see the 400 errors?

Comment: I said that after editing the http-vhosts.conf file the frontend loaded. This wouldn't be possible if the DNS hadn't been configured properly first. I've updated my question with an example API call in the backend.

Comment: Unless you were making the request from the server itself :) Just to be clear, you're saying a request to `http://framework.example.com` works, but a request to `http://framework.example.com/api/example` doesn't?

Comment: Yeh, after editing the http-vhosts to point to the correct folder, the frontend would load, so `http://framework.example.com` works, but when my frontend Angular makes a call to `http://framework.example.com/api/example` I get the 400 error. I can see why, because the routing of the domain in this way is just standard apache routing. But it needs to link to the app somehow.

Comment: I've updated my question again with file structure for the app.

Comment: Okay, that helps. You're basically running apache in front of your node app. That's not ideal, but we can work with it. You'll need to use ProxyPass (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass). Update with your vhosts config and I'll update my answer with ProxyPass added.